# Vectors and Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

The main issue with vectors and pointers to their elements is that they can be reallocated in memory whenever a `push_back` is called, rendering the pointer invalid.

I am trying to implement a suffix trie, where I store a data structure `node` in a vector of nodes. I know that for a string of size *n* the number *n(n+1)/2* is an upperbound for the number of nodes in the trie.

So will the code

```c++
std::string T = "Hello StackOverflow!";
std::vector<Node> nodes;

int n = T.length();
nodes.reserve(n*(n+1)/2);
```

guarantee that any pointers I create referring to elements of `nodes` will not be invalidated? i.e. will this guarantee that the vector is not reallocated?

---

**Edit**: I've implemented this and I keep getting the following error at runtime.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
what():  basic_string::at: __n (which is 0) >= this->size() (which is 0)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Check out `std::deque`. `push_back` doesn't invalidate references/pointers (but iterators are invalidated). http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque

Comment: @Kevin: The question is about `std:::vector`, not `std::deque` though :).

Comment: @AlexD I know, I'm just mentioning an alternative if he wants a container that supports `push_back` and doesn't invalidate references. `std::deque` has its uses but is often ignored. The answers below are probably fine for this question though.

Answer (score 5):

According to the standard (`N4140`):

> **23.3.6.3 vector capacity**
>   ....
>
> ```
> void reserve(size_type n);
> ```
>
> ....
>   After `reserve()`, `capacity()` is greater or equal to the argument of reserve if
>   reallocation happens; and equal to the previous value of `capacity()` otherwise. Reallocation happens
>   at this point if and only if the current capacity is less than the argument of `reserve()`.

and

> **23.3.6.5 vector modifiers**
>   ....
>
> ```
> void push_back(const T& x);
> void push_back(T&& x);
> ```
>
> *Remarks:* Causes reallocation if the new size is greater than the old capacity. If no reallocation happens,
>   all the iterators and references before the insertion point remain valid.

Comment: But will `resereve()` fix the capacity of the vector the the given size?

Comment: @LukeCollins that is exactly what the `reserve` function does

Comment: The standard: _After reserve(), capacity() is greater or equal to the argument of reserve if
reallocation happens; and equal to the previous value of capacity() otherwise._

Comment: @M.M Thank you - I wasn't sure if it had any conditions. So given that I am sure that my vector exceeds *n(n+1)/2*, I should be fine?

Answer (score 3):

You can be certain that your pointers will not be invalidated if you are careful. See [std::vector::push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back). It says this about invalidation :

> **If the new size() is greater than capacity()** then all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated. Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated.

Simply make sure you do not `push_back` beyond capacity or call other methods that may invalidate. A list of methods that invalidate is available [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) in section 'Iterator invalidation'.

Comment: But will `resereve()` fix the capacity of the vector the the given size?

Comment: @LukeCollins [std::vector::reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) does not set capacity to an exact value, but it does guarantee that the new capacity will be *at least as large* as the value supplied to `reserve`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you help me with the edit above?

Comment: @LukeCollins this is an unrelated problem. From the error message, you are access the first character of a string that contains no characters.

Comment: #Francois, could you help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41558092/accessing-the-first-character-of-a-string-with-no-characters