# Accessing the first Character of a String with no Characters

Tags: c++, runtime-error, suffix-tree, suffix-array, suffix

I am implementing a suffix trie in C++. The implementation of the `Trie` contructor can be seen below.

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "Trie.hpp"
using namespace std;

Trie::Trie(string T){   
    T += "#";                           //terminating character     
    this->T = T;

    nodes.reserve(T.length() * (T.length() + 1) / 2);   //The number of nodes is bounded above by n(n+1)/2. The reserve prevents reallocation (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41557421/vectors-and-pointers/41557463) 

    vector<string> suffix;              //vector of suffixes
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < T.length(); i++)
        suffix.push_back(T.substr(i, T.length()-i));

    //Create the Root, and start from it
    nodes.push_back(Node(""));          //root has blank label
    Node* currentNode = &nodes[0];

    //While there are words in the array of suffixes
    while(!suffix.empty()){

        //If the character under consideration already has an edge, then this will be its index. Otherwise, it's -1.
        int edgeIndex = currentNode->childLoc(suffix[0].at(0));     

        //If there is no such edge, add the rest of the word
        if(edgeIndex == -1){
            addWord(currentNode, suffix[0]);                //add rest of word
            suffix.erase(suffix.begin());                   //erase the suffix from the suffix vector
        }

        //if there is
        else{
            currentNode = (currentNode->getEdge(edgeIndex))->getTo();       //current Node is the next Node
            suffix[0] = suffix[0].substr(1, suffix[0].length());            //remove first character
        }           
    }   
}

//This function adds the rest of a word
void Trie::addWord(Node* parent, string word){  
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){                //For each remaining letter
        nodes.push_back(Node(parent->getLabel()+word.at(i)));       //Add a node with label of parent + label of edge
        Edge e(word.at(i), parent, &nodes.back());                  //Create an edge joining the parent to the node we just added
        parent->addEdge(e);                                         //Join the two with this edge   
    }
}
```

I am using two data structures, `Node` and `Edge` which have some getters and setters and properties you would expect. The method `childLoc()` returns the location of an edge (if it exists) representing a given character.

The code compiles just fine, but for some reason I get this error at runtime:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::at: __n (which is 0) >= this->size() (which is 0)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've been told that this error means I am accessing the first character of an empty string, but I can't see where this is happening in the code.

Comment: have you debugged your code with a debugger? e.g. compile with '-g' flag with g++, then use a gdb based debugger to step thru the code...

Comment: It is very difficult to help you with a run time error without being able to compile the example. You should step through the code with a debugger on your end. If you want an answer, you will need to reduce the example and provide input data that produces your problem. See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to produce a helpful example that will attract more answers.

Comment: So somewhere you have confused no string of sausages with a string of no sausages. Easy to do since and std:;string cannot be null, unlike a C char *.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean, can you please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

I see two code parts that are potentially responsible for `std::out_of_range`:

First: The following expression might access an empty string at position `0`. This might happen as (as shown in the second part), you shrink strings contained in the `suffix`-vector:

```
int edgeIndex = currentNode->childLoc(suffix[0].at(0));
```

Second, you operate on the entries in `suffix`-vector with the risk that the strings are to short:

```
suffix[0] = suffix[0].substr(1, suffix[0].length());
```

Operation `substr` will also yield `std::out_of_range` if first operand (i.e. `pos`-argument) exceeds the array length (cf. [string::substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)):

> `pos`: Position of the first character to be copied as a substring. If
>   this is equal to the string length, the function returns an empty
>   string. If this is greater than the string length, it throws
>   out_of_range. Note: The first character is denoted by a value of 0
>   (not 1).

For finding out which of these expressions is actually responsible for the exception, I'd suggest to consult your debugger :-)

Comment: Regarding the first remark, isn't the final string pushed of length `T.length()-(T.length-1)` = 1?

Comment: @Luke Collins: yes, you are right. I adapted the answer accordingly.

Comment: @LukeCollins `suffix[0].substr(1, suffix[0].length())` is going to fail on a 1 character string since there are no characters at index 1.  It's **also** going to fail for every string since the length argument is the full length of the string, yet you're starting at index 1 and hence overflowing the string by one.  If you want to get the string starting at a character index, it's easier to just leave out the length argument.  ie: `s.substr(1)`  gets everything after the first character assuming the string has more than one character to begin with.

Comment: @ebyrob: giving an excessive length to string::substr is not a problem; it's just a max. But you're right, the one-argument version is better.

Comment: @ebyrob Thanks for that. But the way it's written, the suffix[0].substr(1, suffix[0].length()) should never run for a 1 character string no?

Comment: @Like Collins: If `pos` is equal to the string length, the function returns an empty string.

Comment: @LukeCollins You yourself in the first comment to this answer said the last pushed entry would be a 1 character string.